# attr_reader in Python

Tags: python, ruby

Is there a "synonym" for `attr_reader`in python, like something that doesn't have to make me type out?:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, foo, bar, spam, spammity, spam, spam, quux, foobar, barfoo):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
        self.spam = spam
        # And so on...
```

Just a one line thing that makes `self.foo = foo, etc.`, sort of like how ruby's `attr_reader` would make

```
@foo = foo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with kwargs:

```
class Foo():
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.foo = kwargs['foo']
```

And you pass in named arguments:

```
foo = Foo(foo='bar')
```

Of course, you might want to catch KeyError exception

Answer (score 5):

To set everything, try:

```
class Foo():
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    for k,v in kwargs.items():
        setattr(self, k, v)
```

Or just some attributes:

```
class Foo():
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    for k in ['foo', 'bar', 'spam']:
        setattr(self, k, kwargs[k])
```

Or from (some) ctor args:

```
class Foo():
  def __init__(self, foo, bar, spam, bork, kevork):
    for k in ['foo', 'bar']:
        setattr(self, k, locals()[k])
```

Or all of them:

```
class Foo():
  def __init__(self, foo, bar, spam, bork, kevork):
    args = dict(locals())
    for k, v in (k,v for k,v in args.items() if not k == 'self'):
        setattr(self, k, v)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use setattr to set self attr from keyword named args.

```
>>> class Foo():
...     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
...         for attr_name in kwargs.keys():
...             setattr(self,attr_name,kwargs[attr_name])
... 
>>> j=Foo(it_works='cool!!')
>>> j.it_works
'cool!!'
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do can be done entirely with positional args using `locals()`:

```
class Foo():
   def __init__(self, foo, bar, spam, spammity, spaam, 
                spamm, quux, foobar, barfoo):
       self.__dict__.update(locals())

f = Foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
print f.spamm   # 6
```

(I changed two of your `spam`s in the arglist because Python doesn't like having more than one argument with the same name.)

Note that *all* locals will be made into attributes on the instance. This can be convenient if you want to initialize a bunch of attributes statically, since you won't need to type `self` in front of them:

```
class Foo():
   def __init__(self, foo, bar, spam, spammity, spaam, 
                spamm, quux, foobar, barfoo):
       a = b = c = 0
       self.__dict__.update(locals())   # sets a, b, and c too
```

However, if you accept keyword arguments, you'll want to exclude that variable from the update, or more likely just `del self.kwargs` afterward.